# How to put br tag after the dot in the second position

Tags: python

I want to put the `<br>` after the discovery of the `.` in the second position, as exemplified below.

```
str = "Lorem ipsum amet. consectetur adipisicing elit. sed do eiusmod magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum amet. consectetur adipisicing elit. sed do eiusmod magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."
```

expected results:

```
str = "Lorem ipsum amet. consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> sed do eiusmod magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum amet. <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. sed do eiusmod magna aliqua. <br> Ut enim ad minim veniam."
```

I try to use this script:

```
s = "During a November 2014 trip to Los Angeles. Boston-based Snapchat creator. Mike Platco stopped by Snap's Venice. CA offices to say hello."
index = [i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c=='.']
data = []
for x in index:
    text = s[:x*2].replace('. ', '. <br>')
    data.append(text)

print data
```

result :

```
['During a November 2014 trip to Los Angeles. <br>Boston-based Snapchat creator. <br>Mike Plat', "During a November 2014 trip to Los Angeles. <br>Boston-based Snapchat creator. <br>Mike Platco stopped by Snap's Venice. <br>CA offices to say hello.", "During a November 2014 trip to Los Angeles. <br>Boston-based Snapchat creator. <br>Mike Platco stopped by Snap's Venice. <br>CA offices to say hello.", "During a November 2014 trip to Los Angeles. <br>Boston-based Snapchat creator. <br>Mike Platco stopped by Snap's Venice. <br>CA offices to say hello."]
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am still confused to give it a try. hopefully here I can find a way for this case.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing or tutorial service. Take the [tour], learn [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regular expression springs to mind but you can also use good old join and split.

```
source = "Lorem ipsum amet. consectetur adipisicing elit. sed do eiusmod magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum amet. consectetur adipisicing elit. sed do eiusmod magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."
#break it up into a list separated by dots
split_src = source.split(".")
#loop through the list modifying every second one
for i in range(2, len(split_src)-1, 2):
   split_src[i] = "<br>" + split_src[i]
#join the lines up again with a dot
result = ".".join(split_src)
```

Admittedly, there is no check above to see if there are more than 2 phrases (meaning that the indexing [2] would fail if the source only had 2 phrases) but you should get the idea.

Comment: thanks for reply. but, I want to add `br` after the` .` second and so did so on.

Comment: Edited to add the range loop stepping over every second dot

Comment: Thanks Will, I will develop the script of your needs in this case.